# List view navigation in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-navigation

My activity contains two vertically separated fragments.

- Left fragment contains  `ListView` containing five different categories. Right fragment shows content corresponding to a category.
- Right fragment contains a  `RecyclerView` which contains number of custom views(icon and string label).

Issue is when I am at first option in left fragment(first element of list view) and press Right navigation key then focus properly transfers to the first custom view of Right fragment. But when I am on other than first option, focus does not transfer to the custom view, instead it transfers to the recycler view.

I am setting **setFocusable** and **onFocusChangeListener** properties to each custom view.

So can anybody tell what I am missing?

**EDIT** code snippets:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="20">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:background="@color/lightBlue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView adapter code snippet:

```
drawable = holder.itemView.getBackground();
holder.itemView.setFocusable(true);
holder.itemView.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener);
```

Fragment Side bar:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbars="none"/>
```

ListView ArrayAdapter code snippet:

```
convertView.setTag(categoryClass)
```

categoryClass contains two elements icon and label.

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: @lawstud okk I am editing.